# Import typescript module declarations only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, module, export

I have multiple React projects where I need to declare same typescript modules every time, e.g. fonts.d.ts:

```
declare module "*.woff";
declare module "*.woff2";
```

or images.d.ts:

```
declare module "*.jpg" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
declare module "*.png" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

I want to create a package with such types which would be included in each project I'm working on, so I would not create and update module declaration files in each project. Cannot figure out how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot figure out how to do that?

## Create the code

- `npm init -y`.
- To your package.json add: `"types": "/index.d.ts"`
- Name your package something that isn't already taken.
- Create a file `index.d.ts` with the contents that you want to include.
- `npm publish`

## Use the code

- Install your package `npm i your-package`.
- Add `types: ['your-package']` to the tsconfig.json.

I'm making a few assumptions here, like the ability to publish to npm, but this should help you research further and solve for your *particular* requirements. Have fun

Comment: Is it possible to define them in another existing package, where `index.d.ts` is already being built to `/dist` and it is not possible to add additional file to `"types"` in package.json? (because arrays are not allowed)